It's right in front of you
What should replace the question mark and which three words is it equal to? (I've given you one of them - per).
?   =  ----- per ------


It's a known "equation/formula" and there's a little bit of wordplay going on in the question (on a single word).

At first I thought something along the lines of rot13[gur fperra gung lbh'er ivrjvat guvf chmmyr guebhtu (urapr gur gvgyr). Vavgvnyyl V gubhtug fbzrguvat yvxr "oyhrf naq terraf" (ersreevat gb ETO) ohg vg frrzf yvxr n irel jrnx nafjre.] Just food for thought.

I'm soon gonna add a tag which I think will be very useful and which I intentionally left out. After that, I'll wait for some days for the next hint if it's not solved.

Adding hints does not make a puzzle less broad. Hints are supposed to be unnecessary supplemental information - if a puzzle is ambiguous based on non-hidden material, then it's ambiguous. If you find that more restrictions are necessary, those have to be visible, not hints

Voted to reopen since the answer is pretty clear now

The question mark should be replaced by

 WATT

and it is equal to a

 JOULE PER SECOND, as a Watt is a unit of power with this value.

We know this because the title says

 "It's right in front of you", and with the Lateral Thinking tag, we see in front of us the statement "What should replace the question mark". So the word 'What' should replace the question mark - but with the Wordplay tag/instruction ("on a single word"), this is treated as if the instructions were read aloud, causing us the hear the instructions "Watt should replace the question mark."
 This is confirmed because the definition of "watt" fits the blanks _____ per ______, and is an equation/formula, whereas the definition of "what" does not fit the blanks and is not an equation/formula!


Little nitpick, the watt is a unit of power, the joule a unit of energy.

This is indeed the intended answer, well done!

The question mark should be replaced by

2

which is equal to

WORDS PER IAMBUS.

Why? First, using the knowledge tag,

an iambus is an unstressed syllable followed by a stressed syllable.

Next, using the title,

what is "right in front of you"? Why, the title itself, of course!

It's right in front of you is a line of iambic trimeter because it has three iambi: (1) It's right, (2) in front, and (3) of you.

Finally, notice that

each iambus has exactly two words! Therefore, the title has 2 WORDS PER IAMBUS.

Update: This answer happens to also satisfy the new wordplay hint.

The question asks "...which three words is it equal to?" There is a little bit of wordplay on the final to, which hints that the three words equal two.


This type of thinking can lead to the answer intended, but it's not what I had in mind. It's a known equation.

Nothing to do with syllables though.

@Prim3numbah Aww, I thought it fit all the clues. How are we supposed to know in advance whether our answer happens to be the one you're thinking of?

I think you'll know (given all the hints by now and the tag I'm about to add) that it's the right answer.

Inspired by blue herrings comment
The question mark should be

 The puzzling stack exchange logo
 


 The three words are the colors GREEN RED YELLOW.


 This fits in with the title very nicely as it is right in front of us!!


Nice attempt, but no this is not the intended answer. It doesn't make use of the knowledge-tag and it's a bit arbitrary.

The solution could be

 k = force / length

This is the well-known formulation of

Hooke's law, defining the spring constant.

This fits the wordplay because

 "what" should replace the question mark. The Spanish word for "what" is "que", pronounced "k".


Perhaps it’s:

 Meta-question = ”Solve the puzzle”

 Because the puzzle is in front of me.


No this is not it either

Could it be

 Surface tension = force per (unit) length

From the wordplay tag:

 The letter 'T' (which can be used to represent the surface tension in mathematical equations) is "right in front of you" ('U')


I was actually thinking that one might come up with this type of thinking, but the "wordplay" refers to something different.

I think it’s

 TAP = TOUCH THE SCREEN

because

 it’s right in front of me.


No, this is not it (knowledge-tag not being used)

I might be totally wrong on this one, but the first
thing that comes to my mind would be:

 mpg = miles per gallon

Why?

 At least while driving that reading is (more or less) always on my dash
 and could also be written as miles / gallon...

 Eh, well - actually "my" reading shows "l / 100km". Mostly somewhat under 7.. ;)\


You got the right word for /, but the rest is not what's intended. By equation I mean a known equation, this is more explaining the abbreviation.

Here is an answer

 twenty $= $ eight add twelve


Good idea, but IMHO too temporary and individual.

Maybe, suppose it should include the title somehow...

No, this is not it (doesn't make use of the knowledge-tag nor the title)
